# Returning page HTML from ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, view

I have a view That Renders 3 grids what I would like to do is on the click of button return the page as a string so I can save the HTML of that Page.

is this possible?

Thanks

ashga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may checkout this [article](http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2010/01/23/aspnet-mvc-2-render-template-to-string) illustrating how to render a view to a string.